# C# Android Apk file title contains "signed" when app is not signed

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-signing

I build't an android app in visual studio community 2015 with xamarin. My template is blank app(android).

When I check release, and go under build and click export android package(.apk), it builds the .apk under:

C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\Release

It builds 2 apk files:

One named ProjectName.ProjectName.apk but also another one named ProjectName.ProjectName-signed.apk

I didn't sign my android application, so I dont know why it says signed in the title, should it not be ProjectName.ProjectName-unsigned.apk

Why does the title include signed? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you build for release it needs to be signed. Most likely its signed with the default signing key.

Comment: @X3Btel        How do i sign it with my own information?

Comment: Sorry havent used xamarin. but check this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/

Comment: @X3Btel        I found out out that i had to go to: tools => android => publish android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the options > Android Package Signing in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio. If a custom signing key is not specified it is most likely being signed with the auto generated debug.keystore.

You can confirm by opening a command prompt going to your java > jdk > bin path and running the following command:

*jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk*

If the result is **CN=Android Debug** then it was signed with the debug.keystore.